# Rewrite AspNetCore Internal WebHost Request to https

Tags: .net-core

I have a proxy in front of my aspnet core app which handles https and I use forwarded headers to my app. This all works except there are some problems with authentication middleware. Upon investigating the logs I noticed that all internal requests are being made with HTTP:

```
[04:59:31 Infor] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://openid.example.com/signin-facebook?code=A...
```

Ofcourse, I never instructed my app to use https anyway, but how to make my app request https instead of http without setting up an https endpoint?

Comment: likely depends on your proxy... can you update your question with some details about proxy, hosting, etc?  (eg: NGINX reverse proxy to kestrel)